# Cloud2Edge package: error connectivity:connection.id.enforcement.failed

Tags: eclipse-ditto, eclipse-iot

I'm testing a deployment of the Eclipse IoT Cloud2Edge package and have followed the instructions here https://www.eclipse.org/packages/packages/cloud2edge/tour/ to test. After creating the new tenant and device, and configuring the connection between Hono and Ditto, I can send telemetry to the new device via the Hono http adapter as shown here:

```
curl -i -u my-auth-id-1@my-tenant:my-password -H 'application/json' --data-binary '{
  "topic": "my-tenant/org.acme:my-device-1/things/twin/commands/modify",
  "headers": {},
  "path": "/features/temperature/properties/value",
  "value": 53
}' http://${HTTP_ADAPTER_IP}:${HTTP_ADAPTER_PORT_HTTP}/telemetry
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
vary: origin
content-length: 0
```

and expected to see this property value updated in Ditto. The updated device property value does not update in Ditto, and when I check the Ditto logs I see the following entries:

```
2022-02-13 20:11:35,265 INFO  [] o.e.d.c.s.m.a.AmqpConsumerActor akka://ditto-cluster/system/sharding/connection/3/hono-connection-for-my-tenant/pa/$a/c1/amqpConsumerActor-0-telemetry%2Fmy-tenant-010 - Received message from AMQP 1.0 with externalMessageHeaders: {orig_adapter=hono-http, qos=0, device_id=org.acme:my-device-1, creation-time=1644783095260, message-id=ID:AMQP_NO_PREFIX:GenericSenderLink-12, content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, to=telemetry/my-tenant, orig_address=/telemetry}
2022-02-13 20:11:35,271 INFO  [81c41f10-4d59-435b-8ae1-bf5194dcf6bf] o.e.d.c.s.m.InboundDispatchingSink  - onMapped mappedHeaders ImmutableDittoHeaders [{ditto-entity-id=thing:my-tenant:org.acme:my-device-1, ditto-inbound-payload-mapper=default, content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, hono-device-id=org.acme:my-device-1, ditto-reply-target=0, ditto-expected-response-types=["response","error"], ditto-origin=hono-connection-for-my-tenant, ditto-auth-context={"type":"pre-authenticated-connection","subjects":["pre-authenticated:hono-connection"]}, correlation-id=81c41f10-4d59-435b-8ae1-bf5194dcf6bf}]
2022-02-13 20:11:35,278 INFO  [b3b11410-6df8-4bfc-a940-fafa87d65be2] o.e.d.c.s.m.InboundDispatchingSink  - Got exception <connectivity:connection.id.enforcement.failed> when processing external message with mapper <default>: <The configured filters could not be matched against the given target with ID 'org.acme:my-device-1'.>
2022-02-13 20:11:35,278 INFO  [b3b11410-6df8-4bfc-a940-fafa87d65be2] o.e.d.c.s.m.InboundDispatchingSink  - Resolved mapped headers of ImmutableDittoHeaders [{ditto-inbound-payload-mapper=default, ditto-entity-id=thing:my-tenant:org.acme:my-device-1, response-required=false, content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, hono-device-id=org.acme:my-device-1, ditto-reply-target=0, ditto-expected-response-types=["response","error"], ditto-origin=hono-connection-for-my-tenant, ditto-auth-context={"type":"pre-authenticated-connection","subjects":["pre-authenticated:hono-connection"]}, correlation-id=b3b11410-6df8-4bfc-a940-fafa87d65be2}] : with HeaderMapping Optional[ImmutableHeaderMapping [mapping={hono-device-id={{ header:device_id }}, content-type={{ header:content-type }}}]] : and external headers {orig_adapter=hono-http, qos=0, device_id=org.acme:my-device-1, creation-time=1644783095260, message-id=ID:AMQP_NO_PREFIX:GenericSenderLink-12, content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, to=telemetry/my-tenant, orig_address=/telemetry}
2022-02-13 20:11:35,283 INFO  [] o.e.d.c.s.m.a.AmqpConsumerActor akka://ditto-cluster/system/sharding/connection/3/hono-connection-for-my-tenant/pa/$a/c1/amqpConsumerActor-0-telemetry%2Fmy-tenant-010 - Acking <ID:AMQP_NO_PREFIX:GenericSenderLink-12> with original external message headers=<{orig_adapter=hono-http, qos=0, device_id=org.acme:my-device-1, creation-time=1644783095260, message-id=ID:AMQP_NO_PREFIX:GenericSenderLink-12, content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, to=telemetry/my-tenant, orig_address=/telemetry}>, isSuccess=<true>, ackType=<1 accepted>
```

I think the problem is the "connectivity:connection.id.enforcement.failed" error but I don't know how to troubleshoot. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you configured is the [Connection source enforcement](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/basic-connections.html#source-enforcement) which makes sure that a Hono device (identified via the AMQP header `device_id`) may only updates the twin with the same "thing id" in Ditto.

That enforcement fails as your thingId you set in the Ditto Protocol JSON is `my-tenant:org.acme:my-device-1` - the `topic`'s first segment is the namespace, the second segment the name - combined those 2 segments become the "thing ID", see also: [Protocol topic](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/protocol-specification-topic.html) specification.

So you probably want to send the following message instead:

```json
{
  "topic": "org.acme/my-device-1/things/twin/commands/modify",
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I was getting confused between namespaces and tenants in the addressing (and the : vs / notation). All sorted now, thanks for your help.